# Php - Pass multiple headers with one function

Tags: php, http, header, http-post

I have route function, which corrects the URI with the given "friendly URL" rules. If some part is missing or incorrect, it changes to valid form and then redirect function throws location header with the correct URL.

```
function redir($controller_name,$action_name){
    $root = '/' . Model::$rootSite . '/';
    $fullSite = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$root.
    $controller_name.'/'.$action_name;
    header('Location: '.$fullSite);
}
```

Nothing new... But! If there is a form, on the first iteration, before redirect, it sends $_POST data which can be handled. But how can i throw it further to the next iteration accompanying valid URL in redirect function?
The header function can achieve multiple http headers? What's the correct syntax?

Comment: You can call `header()` multiple times, to add different headers. But I'm not sure that's what you're asking.

Comment: You can have multiple headers which can be individually executed based on conditions but you can only pass one header per page otherwise you get the headers already sent error.

Comment: You can't redirect a `POST` request. The redirection is always processed using `GET` and won't send the post data.